# Looking for a list of valid email addresses to test if email sending is working (not input validation)

Tags: email-validation

I am trying to set up a test for our email system (via mailgun).

I am wondering if there are 1000 valid email addresses anywhere that we could send emails for testing purposes. These would need to be valid addresses that can receive email but shouldn't be used by a real human (we don't want to spam).

I don't want to use fake email addresses because this may cause many bouncebacks and damage our reputation score.

So, this is not really about email validation, it is about having addresses to test the sending of emails.

Comment: You could sign up to 1000 mailing lists or something, but I'm guessing that's not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears mailinator.com offers a free service to accomplish this.